# Why inline swapping returns unexpected result?

Tags: python, swap

I am trying to swap two objects in python like this `A[i], A[A[i] - 1] = A[A[i] - 1], A[i]` is not giving me the correct output

According to the order of operation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order
the right hand side is resolved first and then do the assignment from left to right. 
Suppose `i = 1` then we get `A[1], A[3] = A[3], A[1]`

Suppose `A = [-1, 4, 3, 1]`  and `i = 1` where i is an index

```
A[i], A[A[i] - 1] = A[A[i] - 1], A[i]
```

I get `[4,1,3,1]` as the result even though I expected to get `[-1, 1,3,4]` i.e. `A[1], A[3] = A[3], A[1]`

But when I do this I get the correct `[-1,1,3,4]`. Why does this one work and the above does not?

```
A[A[i] - 1], A[i] = A[i], A[A[i] - 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to assign `A[A[i] - 1]`, `A[i]` has already changed.

Let's break it down with `i = 1`:

First, the right hand side expressions are evaluated:

- At this point `A[i]` = `A[1]` = `4`
- So `A[A[i]-1]` = `A[4-1]` = `A[3]` = `1`

Now the assignments from left to right:

- `A[i]` = `A[1]` <- `1`
- `A[A[i]-1]` = `A[1-1]` = `A[0]` <- `4`
- final result: `[4, 1, 3, 1]`

Comment: but if we have x, y = y, x what I thought was y and x are evaluated and stored first and then the assignment goes from left to right. So, if we evaluate rhs we get A[3] and A[1] which are stored temporarily and then we do left to right assignment. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, the values are not stored as `A[3]` and `A[1]`, they are stored as the actual values `1` and `4`. Then when evaluating `A[A[i]-1]` of the LHS, `A[i]` has already changed from the first assignment, regardless of the values stored prehand

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the assignments occur from left to right, and `A[i]` is modified before `A[A[i] - 1]` is evaluated to determine the target for the second assignment.

In you second example, the assignment to `A[A[i] - 1]` does not affect the result of `A[i]` for the second assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution of inline swapping is little complex.

**First** the right hand side is evaluated which forms a tuple of two elements - `(A[3], A[1])` and is stored in memory. This is calculated prior and it's value is fixed and does not depend on whatever this assignment does. So we have `(1, 4)` on the right side.

**Secondly**, the values are assigned to left hand from left side:

1. First `A[i]` is assigned `A[3]` i.e., **`A[i] = 1`**.
2. Then `A[A[i] - 1]` becomes `A[1 - 1]` which is `A[0]` assigned as 4.